# MongoDB 3.2 Disk Usage Limit Per Database?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to limit MongoDB 3.2's database usage by database name?

Creating databases using `use databasename` is easy, and displaying usage is also easy with

```
> show dbs;

admin        0.000GB
jon1         0.001GB
jon2         0.477GB
local        0.014GB
```

Is there a built-in way to limit the usage of `jon2` database to 0.500 GB?  I would like to return an error on `db.jon2.insert` when the size is exceeded, if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: This is answered here : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64065/how-to-limit-mongodb-database-size

Comment: That works for an entire mongodb instance.  I want to limit the size of just one database within the instance, if possible. So `jon1` has a 250 MB limit, and `jon2` has a 500 MB limit.

Comment: I just found `https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-proxy` maybe I can use it to catch and error when a database has reached its limit..

Comment: The quota file setting can limit the maximum number of files that can be allocated for a specific database, but the setting is only valid for the MMAP storage engine (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#storage.mmapv1.quota.enforced). File allocation in WiredTiger is completely different, so this setting isn't applicable for this storage engine.